# Switched-cap/charge pump only way to generate negative rail voltage for op-amp?

Tags: amplifier, differential, instrumentation-amplifier, negative

I need to design a daughterboard that gets mounted directly to a piezo mic to condition the signal before transmission. Part of the conditioning is a full wave rectification.

Thus, as you'd expect with a transducer we'll read a differential voltage dipping as far down as -2.5V on the differential amp. Despite my searches I suppose no one yet makes a "single supply" instrumentation op amp that generates its own negative reference? (>-0.3V).

Size is imperative here and being able to exclude even an SMD switched-cap/charge pump to generate my negative reference would be highly useful. Any suggestions?

Comment: It would be normal to generate a local "0V" at half the supply voltage, -ve is then -ve wrt that. Would that work for your app?

Comment: What power supply will the daughterboard receive?

Comment: My apologizes, I forgot to include that important detail. The daughterboard receives a 4-conductor cable. Sgnl+, Sgnl-, and +5VDC (&Gnd/Sheild). Edit--> forgot I actually do have a shield/gnd.